# Issue with changing datatype in Glue Data catalog table

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a database called testDB in the AWS Glue Data Catalog. I have an Iceberg table called testtable1 in this database. This table has a column called column3 which is of datatype int. I want to change the data type of this column from int to string. I am unable to run an alter statement on this table to change the datatype since Iceberg allows only certain datatype changes. I also tried to change the datatype in the backend metadata file to see if it works, but it doesn't work.
If I try to drop the column and re-add it, it adds the column to the end of the table and I lose all the data present in the column for that table.
Is there any way of achieving this without dropping the column?